# Adding QuickBlox JS SDK titanium sdk

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, quickblox

I'm trying to integrate chat module from `QuickBlox` into my titanium project
what i have done is downloaded quickblox module using npm 
then i copied the quickblox.js file to my project
and i have downloaded a sample file for connecting to server
the same code works fine on the web but when i try to run it in the app i got an error in quickblox.js saying

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.sigBytes')
```

any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: If you are using the javascript version of Quickblox, you will have to create a webview and use the js inside the webview.

Comment: so if the titanium based on java script so why i could not use JS SDK like android or iOS SDK?

Comment: Titanium is basically a JS lib which maps to native sdk of ios and android; so if Quickblox uses any browser related stuff it has to be opened in webview.

Comment: After trying the above, please check with version 1.7.2 here: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk/blob/master/quickblox.min.js The sigBytes is a crypto-js error, but I can't reproduce this with the 1.7.2 library.

Comment: i m getting this error now  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 6338;
[ERROR] :      line = 3;
[ERROR] :      message = "Object is not a function (evaluating 'g(l,m)')